# Why value of 'i' is printing 3 times, it should only print 1 time in insertion sort algorithm

Tags: java

//programme of insertion sort i am checking how many times the value is printing 
//when i enter the 2 and 1 the value of i is printing 3 times but it should have to print 1 times when i enter 2 value

public class Insertionsort {

```
static void insertsort(int arr[]){

    for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
        for(int j=i-1;j>=0;) {
            System.out.println("i is"+i);
            if(arr[j]>arr[i] ) {
                int temp=arr[j];  //for swapping 
                arr[j]=arr[i];
                arr[i]=temp;
                i--;
            }else {
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int arr[]=new int[2];
    System.out.println("please Enter the value");
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
        arr[i]=sc.nextInt();

    }
    insertsort( arr);

}

}
```

Output
please Enter the value
2
1
i is1
i is0
i is1
1
2

Answer (score 1):

The `println` should be before the inner loop.

```
for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
    System.out.println("i is"+i);
    for(int j=i-1;j>=0;) {
```

You only want the value of `i` to be printed once each time `i` is updated. If you put it in the inner loop, then each value of `i` will be printed multiple times since the inner loop can iterate multiple times for each value of `i`.

Comment: in this it printing the i two times when given the intput 2 and 1 but it should print the i only one times as condition is false when i become 2

Answer (score 0):

For value 2,1 it's printing 3 times, because
for i = 1, j= 0 it prints **1 times** then goes inside if condition and makes value of i=0 and no change in value of j and now the value is 1 2 of the array as it is swap.
Again it check condition for j>=0 which satisfies the for loop condition, it enter print **2nd times** but this time it goes to else condition decreasing the value of j making it equal to j=-1, checks the condition and loop exit from inner loop.

At this point we have value of i =0, now it goes to outside loop increases value of i, i.e. makes value of i = 1, checks condition and then goes inside inside inner loop, with j= 0,check condition and then print **3rd times** goes to else condition decreasing the value of j, breaking inner loop and then outer loop.

Try doing dry run or using debugger it will help!